# Generic и массивы

Tags: java, generics

Доброго всем времени!
Думал, что я знаю, как использовать дженерики, а оказалось xто и нет. Код:

```
class MyClass<T> {
   T mas[];

   void foo() {
       mas = new T[10]; // ошибка!
   }
}
```

Вопрос - почему возникает ошибка?

Comment: зачем Вы так делаете? какая цель?

Comment: чисто вспомнить, что и как... к собеседованию готовлюсь.. решил написать несколько сортировок, и вот как всегда у меня бывает, делаю одно, цепляюсь за другое, а спотыкаюсь на третьем... правда в большинстве случаев бывает продуктивным - узнаю то, что раньше не знал)

Comment: я просто не могу себе представить ситуацию когда такое нужно

Comment: @vinger4: мне в C# несколько раз пригодилось. Например, для функции, которая группирует входную последовательность по `k` штук и выдаёт последовательность групп:

    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> BufferBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, int n)
    {
        T[] buffer;
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var t in self)
        {
            if (index == 0) buffer = new T[n];
            buffer[index++] = t;
            if (index == n)
            {
                yield return buffer;
                index = 0;
            }
        }
        if (buffer != null) yield return buffer;
    }

Comment: @nightin_gale, если готовитесь к собеседованию, очень рекомендую заодно повторить ковариантность и контравариантность дженериков,  рекурсивное расширение типа:

 - `oo<? extends Bar>`
 - `Foo<? super Bar>` 
 - `Foo<?>`
 - `Foo<E extends Foo> implements Bar<E>`

Comment: @Nofate: Эрик вот [ругается](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx) на рекурсивные генерики.

Comment: Я рекомендую, то что могут спросить на интервью. А не с точки зрения хорошо-плохо ) 

Если на собеседовании ТС будет настолько владеть темой, что сможет аргументированно выделить bad practices, то это еще больший плюс.

Comment: @Nofate: невозможно сказать лучше.

Answer (score 17):

Это ограничение реализации дженериков в Java.

Дело в том, что дженерики — конструкция времени компиляции, информации о настоящем типе в рантайме нет. Это называется [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html): Java заменяет везде `T` на `Object` в скомпилированном коде (если нет дальнейших условий). При создании массива, однако, Java нуждается в *информации о типе элементов*, но этот тип недоступен, дженерик не имеет возможности узнать тип своего параметра `T`!

Поэтому и создать массив неизвестного (для дженерика) типа `T` в Java невозможно.

---

В качестве рекламы [корпорации мирового зла](http://www.troll.me/images2/obvious-yoda/microsoft-the-dark-side-of-the-force-uses.jpg) замечу, что дженерики в C# были разработаны с учётом опыта Java и избежали проблемы, с которой вы столкнулись[.](http://i.chzbgr.com/completestore/2008/10/30/128698794866102946.jpg)

---

На [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/182636/276994) обсуждаются возможные workaround'ы. Самый простой — передавать `T.class` в конструкторе `MyClass<T>`, и конструировать массив следующим образом:

```
mas = (T[])Array.newInstance(TClass, 10);
```

Comment: вот оно как!!! очень и очень благодарен, особенно в сравнении с Корпорацией!) а как же мне тогда избежать этого?

Comment: В качестве workaround'а можно передавать тип `T` в качестве входного параметра:

    Class TClass = // как-то получить класс T
    T[] ts = (T[])Array.newInstance(TClass, 10);

TClass можно, например, передать в качестве параметра в `foo`:

    MyClass<String> object = ...;
    object.foo(String.class);

Или в конструкторе, и потом запомнить в переменной.

Знаю, некрасиво, сорри.

Comment: прошу прощение за идиотизм моего сабжа, но... щас делаю как вы указали и до меня доходит одно... мало того, что при создании класса я указываю тип, так еще мне нужно будет и в функцию в качестве аргумента тип передавать? Исправьте, пожалуйста, если я ошибся.. Я что-то смутно представляю инициализацию моего массива.. = (

Comment: @nightin_gale: Угу, указывать два раза: как параметр дженерика и как параметр конструктора :-( Я ж говорил, что некрасиво.

Вот пример: http://ideone.com/VhVs6Y

Comment: реально, громадное спасибо!!!

Comment: @nightin_gale: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD, @nightin_gale Чтобы повысить типобезопасность данного костыля, стоит заменить сигнатуру конструктора с

    public MyClass(Class tclass)

на

    public MyClass(Class<T> tclass)

Так хотя бы компилятор проверит тип передаваемого класса. В противном случае мы имеем возможность инстанцировать экземпляр таким образом:

    new MyClass<String>(Integer.class);

Comment: @Nofate: спасибо, хорошая идея!

Answer (score 4):

[[@nightin_gale](/users/14292/nightin_gale)](/users/14292/nightin_gale), Еще один вариант так сказать "из жизни": вместо поля `TClass` объявить абстрактный метод в духе:

```
protected Class<T> getClassDef();
```

и, переопределяя его в дочерних классах:

```
public class MyStringClass extends MyClass<String> {   
  protected Class<T> getClassDef() { return String.class; }
}
```

пользоваться в родительском:

```
mas = (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(getClassDef(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не сделать вот так:

```
mas = (T[])(new Object[10]);
```

Comment: Здесь возникнет исключение - `ClassCastException()`. Скомпилируется, но во время присвоения к конкретному типу будет exception, например, если под `T` подразумеваем тип `String`, то при присвоении ссылке типа `String`  - будет ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш случай попадает под одно из ограничений для дженериков - невозможно создать экземпляр массива или переменной параметризованного типа. Как было описано выше во время компиляции вся информация об использовании параметра типа удаляется и подставляется конкретный, указанный вами тип. Необходимо это для обратной совместимости кода. Поэтому и выходит, что Вы пытаетесь создать экземпляр неизвестного типа, что в принципе невозможно. Но можете передавать массив снаружи, при вызове метода.

Мой ответ весьма упрощен, и является неполным, однако все же является одним из решений данной проблемы =)

```
class MyClass<T> {       
T mas[];

   void foo(T arr[]) { 
       mas = arr; 
   }    
}
```

Comment: а зачем, если это внутренняя переменная?

Comment: Иначе это попадает под стандартное ограничение - экземпляр массива параметризованного типа получить нельзя. Либо описанные ранее варианты.
З.Ы. Конструктивная критика приветствуется =)

Comment: параметр arr точно массив? Стоит добавить в ответ описание, что и почему, иначе ответ больше напоминает комментарий.

Comment: Не досмотрел, спасибо за замечание) Надеюсь стало несколько лучше

Comment: определенно лучше чем было.