# Массив неизвестного типа на Java

Tags: java, generics

Есть параметризованный класс (дженерик), в нём есть поле-массив. Нужно в конструкторе с параметром "длина массива" создать массив. Как это сделать?

```
arr = new T[size]; // Нельзя
Array.newInstance(?????,size); // Что передавать в качестве первого параметра?
```

Есть хоть какая-нибудь возможность это сделать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/264255/177345

Answer (score 1):

Так как любой объект наследует от Object то попробуйте именно его.

```
Array.newInstance(Object.class,size);
```

P.S.

тогда можно

```
Object [] arr= new Object[size];
```

Answer (score 0):

Generics существуют только до этапа компиляции. Во время выполнения программы подставляется конкретный тип. Поэтому нельзя создавать массивы типа T (не понятно что есть T) (да и не только массивы).

В этом случае, можно, как советовали использовать общий тип Object,