# Запись в параметризованный массив Java

Tags: java, generics

Имеется класс-обертка для параметризованного массива:

```
public class CatContainer <T> {

    T[] names;

    public CatContainer(){
        names=(T[]) new Object[10];
    }

//  void set(int index, T value){
//      names[index]=value;
//  }

}
```

Насколько я понимаю, если создать экземпляр параметризованного класса следующем образом: `CatContainer<String> cats=new CatContainer<>()` то ссылка `cats` будет указывать на объект со следующей структурой:

```
public class CatContainer {

    Object[] names;

    public CatContainer(){
        names= new Object[10]; // массив не может изменить 
//свой тип, приведение типов отбрасывается
    }

//  void set(int index, Object value){
//      names[index]=value;
//  }

}
```

Но почему же тогда при попытке обратиться к массиву с типом `Object[]` и записать туда элемент типа `String` следующим образом `cats.names[0]="Murzik";` возникает ошибка:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   [Ljava.lang.String;

P.S. Если обратиться к массиву через метод `void set(int index, T value)` следующим образом: `cats.set(0, "Murzik")` то ошибки приведения типов не возникает

P.P.S Вот код класса - клиента:

```
public class GenericsArray {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        CatContainer<String> cats=new CatContainer<>();
        cats.names[0]="Murzik"; //ClassCastException
        cats.set(0, "Murzik");  // OK

        Object[] arr=new Object[10];
        arr[0]="Hello"; //OK

    }

}
```

Comment: покажите код, при выполнении которого возникает ошибка

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov привел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело не в присвоении, сообщение об ошибке говорит о том, что массив типа `Object` (`[Ljava.lang.Object`) не может быть преобразован в массив типа `String` ( `[Ljava.lang.String`).

Проблему можно воспроизвести и без присвоения, просто обратившись к элементу массива.

```
CatContainer<String> cats=new CatContainer<>();
System.out.println(cats.names[0]);
```

либо выполнив безобидную, казалось бы, операцию:

```
System.out.println(((String[])cats.names));
```

Ошибка возникает, т.к. при приведении проверяется *реальный* тип объекта-массива. Это делается из-за того, что в общем случае нельзя безопасно привести массив одного типа к массиву другого типа из-за связанных с такой операцией проблем:

```
Object[] objects = new Object[10];
objects[0] = new Integer(2);
//здесь возникнет ClassCastException
String[] strings = (String[]) objects;
//иначе возникли бы странные проблемы здесь
System.out.println(strings[0].length());
```

Если реальный тип массива совпадает, то приведение сработает нормально.

```
Object[] objects = new String[10];
//ОК
String[] strings = (String[]) objects;
//а вот здесь уже ArrayStoreException
objects[0] = new Integer(2);
```

Внутри обобщенного класса `T` буквально заменяется на `Object`, присвоения и приведения типов работают. Но в вызывающем коде используется конкретный тип со всеми вытекающими приведениями. Например, этот код:

```
CatContainer<String> cats=new CatContainer<>();
System.out.println(cats.names[0]);
```

Фактически заменяется на:

```
CatContainer cats=new CatContainer();
System.out.println(((String[]) cats.names)[0]);
```

**Пути выхода из сложившейся ситуации:**

- не открывайте поле для доступа извне, работайте методами (Вы уже нашли этот способ);
- принимайте объект класса или массива и создавайте массив нужного типа через [`Array.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int...)):

  ```
  import java.lang.reflect.*;
  ...
  //конструктор
  public CatContainer(Class<T> c){
      names=(T[]) Array.newInstance(c, 10);
  }
  ...
  //пример работы с объектом
  CatContainer<String> cats=new CatContainer<>(String.class);
  cats.names[0] = "Murzik";
  System.out.println(cats.names[0]);
  ```
- используйте вместо массива коллекцию, например, [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Смотрите также:

- [Generic и массивы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264255/generic-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B) — вопрос об объявлении массивов в обобщенных классах
- [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java) — такой же вопрос на английском.

Answer (score 5):

- `names` представляет собой `Object[]`
- Вызов `cats.names` - это попытка привести `Object[]` (реальный тип `names`) к `String[]` (generic-тип)
- Это приведение появляется в коде из-за [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html): `T[] names` заменяется на `Object[] names`, а его вызовы - на `(T[])names`. В данном случае - на `((String[])cats.names)`
- Так как подобное приведение невозможно, то кончается оно исключением

В случае же метода `set` всё работает нормально, так как там нет приведений типа: вся работа ведётся напрямую с `Object[]`, как и указано во втором примере кода (условный вид кода после type erasure)

---

Код `names = (T[])new Object[10];` в конструкторе `CatContainer`, кстати, тоже представляет собой "опасную" конструкцию: покуда `T` ничем не ограничен (то есть `T extends Object`) всё нормально: `Object[]` успешно приводится к `Object[]`. Но стоит сделать, например, `<T extends String>`, как знакомая ошибка начнёт проявляться уже прямо в конструкторе

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov `cats.names`. После type erasure код будет выглядеть так: `((String[])cats.names)[0] = ...`

Comment: "Вызов же cats.names - это попытка привести Object[] к String[]"
Где же там попытка приведения типов? Есть массив типа `Object[]`, в который записывается строка, что по идее должно быть разрешено.

Comment: @Regent Угу, увидел. Очень странно  выглядит. Очередная странность дженериков в java

Comment: @Dmitry расписал в ответе подробнее. Приведение типов там появляется на стадии компиляции во время того самого type erasure