# Почему не получается сделать downcast к пользовательскому классу?

Tags: java, hashset

Напишу причину данного и кода и мою проблему. В качестве обучения пытаюсь сам написать **HashSet**. Обычно реализуют данную коллекцию на основе массива, где каждый элемент - связный список (в моем случае класс **Entry**). Почему здесь невозможно преобразовать к массиву, содержащий тип **Entry**? Какой-то метод нужен что ли? Почему тогда компилятор java не ругается, когда мы приводим к **T[]**? В моем случае появляется такая ошибка -

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast
> to class [Lorg.example.CarHashSet$Entry;

---

```
public class CarHashSet<T> implements CarSet<T> {

    private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;
    private Entry[] array;
    int size;
    public CarHashSet() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.array = (Entry[]) new Object[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
    }

    private class Entry {
        T value;
        Entry next;

        private Entry(T value, Entry next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаёте массив объектов `Object[]` и пытаетесь привести его к массиву `Entry[]`, разумеется такой код выбросит исключение, так как на самом деле вам необходимо создать массив обобщённых `Entry`.

[Как давно известно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/264255/), нельзя просто взять и создать массив дженериков:

```java
this.array = new Entry[INITIAL_CAPACITY]; // error: generic array creation
```

Однако, если очень нужно, то можно использовать метод [`java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int)):

```java
this.array = (Entry[]) Array.newInstance(Entry.class, INITIAL_CAPACITY);
```

Кроме того, придётся указать, что класс `Entry` также является обобщённым и соответствующие переменные/параметры, и при приведении типов использовать аннотацию `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` во избежание нежелательных предупреждений от компилятора:

```java
import java.util.reflect.Array;

public class CarHashSet<T> implements Set<T> {

    private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;
    private Entry<T>[] array;
    int size;
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public CarHashSet() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.array = (Entry<T>[]) Array.newInstance(Entry.class, INITIAL_CAPACITY);
    }
    
    private class Entry<T> {
        T value;
        Entry<T> next;

        private Entry(T value, Entry<T> next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
        
        public T value() {return this.value;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает действительно. Однако, я не изменял класс Entry, компилятор совершенно не ругается... Или мне в любом случае надо сделать, как вы написали? Может покажутся глупыми вопросы, просто изначально изучал ООП только на Python... Привык к нему, так сказать....

Comment: Если ответ оказался полезным, можете поставить зелёную галочку.  А касаемо `Entry` -- без указания `<T>` компилятор будет генерировать предупреждения об использовании сырых типов, то есть фактически дженериков у вас и не будет, а только обычные `Object`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за решение моей проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Инициализируя новый `Object` создаётся именно `Object`, который не может быть преобразован к дочернему типу. Нельзя преобразовывать родительские типы к дочерним, как минимум потому что в объектах родительских типов (таких как `Object`) отсутствуют поля из объектов дочерних типов (В твоём случае поле `value` и `next`) (за исключением случаев когда родительский тип хранит в себе как раз объект дочернего типа), можно только наоборот (любой дочерний тип к родительскому типу, так как дочерний объект 100% будет содержать поля родительского объекта)

Comment: Глупый вопрос, возможно, от меня, но почему тогда работает обычно запись `(T[]) new Object[]`? Мы же, условно говоря, под `T` подставляем любой дочерний тип от `Object`, так как `Object` на вершине иерархии. Класс `Integer` хранит что ли все поля, как у `Object`?

Comment: @C3EQUALZ Любой тип (кроме примитивных) хранит все те же поля, что и Object (виртуальные методы типо ToString() тоже считаются полями)

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете просто преобразовать массив объектов к вашему классу Entry. В место этого создайте новый объект класса Entry:

```
public class CarHashSet<T> implements CarSet<T> {

    private static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;
    private Entry array; //без []
    int size;
    public CarHashSet() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.array = new Entry(/* Значение для value */, new Object[INITIAL_CAPACITY]);
    }

    private class Entry {
        T value;
        Entry next;

        public Entry(T value, Entry next) { //публичный конструктор
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, к сожалению, Вы меня чуточку не поняли, мне нужен не отдельный объект класса Entry, а массив, где каждая ячейка - объект класса Entry. Если вам не трудно, то код, где не используются Generic, а обычный класс Car - https://pastebin.com/b0sEnuax . Класс Car - обычная затычка, где есть поле brand и number. Я пытаюсь переделать данный код с использованием Generic.